# Best way to set an API server using Node.js and Postgres?

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I'm new in Node.js. I'm trying to find out and learn which is the best way to set an Api Server, just for CRUD (Create, Read, Update and Delete) requests.

I've being looking around the different server frameworks that are normally used with Node.js:

- Express
- Restify
- Hapi

I'm also using the [node-postgres](http://expressjs.com) library already connecting to the database and making queries, but I haven't found a good guide or example using either of the previous frameworks to set an Api Server with PostgreSQL.

I'd be very thankful is someone could point me to the right direction or show me a basic example.

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Hapi has the best performance. Otherwise I hope this can help you:

http://blog.newrelic.com/2014/08/15/node-js-frameworks-hapi-js-restify-geddy

http://blog.nodeknockout.com/post/34571027029/making-an-api-happy-with-hapi

http://blog.modulus.io/nodejs-and-hapi-create-rest-api

Comment: Thank you! Looks promising. Any Postgres example?